# Microsoft Graph API: query with $search by multiple fields

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to query Graph API messages with match on `to` and `subject` fields,
i.e.: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?$search="to:email@example.com AND subject:something"`

As I understand strict match search will be performed only if I'll wrap subject in double quotes
`$search="to:email@example.com AND subject:"strict match""`
This makes query invalid due to `"` nesting - how should I escape those quotes to make a valid query?

Also assuming I'm looking for a subject like: `quote -> ' double quote -> "`, how should the search param look like with both: to and subject that contains this example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backslash operator to escape the double quotes.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?$search="to:email@example.com AND subject:\"strict match\""

Have a look at Search Tip and Tricks of the article below for appropriate search query:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/policy-and-compliance/ediscovery/message-properties-and-search-operators?view=exchserver-2019#searchable-properties-in-exchange

Search like "subject:\"test\"" returns all the messages where subject line has keyword "test".  Strict search "subject:\"my test\"" returns all the messages where subject line has sentence "my test".

Please have a look at Subject searchable property in the article below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#search-parameter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/policy-and-compliance/ediscovery/message-properties-and-search-operators?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: I tried this and it didn't give me exact match results: `$search="subject:\"test\""` gives me messages with `"subject": "test ' with quote --<",`